# How to bring 3d effect in surface?

Tags: rendering, camera, nurbs-surface

Can anyone tell me how this surface looks like 3d which covers red sphere and blue cylinders.  [image]

see the blend file here
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3570/

Comment: There are many ways to approach the rendering of a surface. What aspects are you most interested in? The more you see the surface, the less you'll see the mulecular structure. Is it a choice to show only the surface in 3D and leave the structure as it is? Can you tell more about your goals? Do you have any reference image?

Comment: Hi @Carlo I want somewhat similar to Penicillin structure  https://github.com/patrickfuller/blender-chemicals   but not too much glassy. Internal molecular and surface both should be visible clearly.

Comment: perhaps, you could try to build it with metaballs, then you could convert them to mesh...

Answer (score 1):

*The primary problem with the lack of visual space is that you're using an* ***Emission Shader*** for the blue and the red.  Emission shaders cannot receive shadows so they look more cartoony for something like this.  I would change the material to ***Diffuse***:

[image]

I added a ***UV Sphere*** with a ***Solidify Modifier*** and mixed the ***Glass Shader*** with ***Transparent*** (mostly transparent) to take the "edge off the glassiness".

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @bertmoog for your good answer. I am trying to repeat what you have done but not getting the same. Can you upload the blend file so that I can see what is the difference between my blend file and your blend file. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user3704712 - No problem: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3573/    - Just open it and press Shift+Z to see render preview.